# Implementing WAL in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I want to implement WAL in Android, but there is not much documentation about this. I read the WAL documentation on SQLite [Here](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html) but its not clear enough on how to port it to Android.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6653648/how-to-implement-write-ahead-logging-of-sqlite-in-java-program) question also sheds some light but I am not sure if executing only one statement will do.

[Background of the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21309808/background-service-and-ui-updates-and-implementing-wal?noredirect=1#comment32117648_21309808)

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: I added the [`database.enableWriteAheadLogging();`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#enableWriteAheadLogging%28%29) in my open() method in a class that I open/close the DB. I think it bugged it since I couldn't see anything in the SQLite Database Browser, but data was available to the app. Maybe I am using it incorrectly, but I hope this is a start.

Comment: @YordanLyubenov The enableWriteAheadLogging function needs to be called only once, after the DB has been created.

Comment: Its exactly teh same for me, there is some bug too also it works only for certain versions of SQlite. have to take all this into consideration.

Comment: It would be great if you provide me with an example or an algo.

Comment: @CL I used one of the PRAGMA functions to do it once in onCreate in my own implementation in the SQLiteOpenHelper class, but it didn't work there. You suggest this is used in there? And, more importantly, used there in onCreate?

Comment: Oops, WAL is persistent but your problem should not be that WAL is not working. It is more likely that your lock is causing trouble since not even WAL allows 2 threads to have write access at the same time. Look at transactions in Immediate mode, that might be something that could help.

Comment: I have only two threads, I got rid of the lock one of the thread will read and one will write. I am researching about it more and will update with details here.

Comment: can't you just call `enableWriteAheadLogging` on your DB? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#enableWriteAheadLogging()

Comment: I am trying something like that only but I am not sure where and how to use these methods, I found something here https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/9a7debe5857ffc7c71cfc4082b1b6d72a5cf81cd/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.java still trying to grasp it.